# Creating Project Cocos2d-x-3.1.1

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have downloaded Cocos2d-x-3.1.1 but it does not include #create-android-project.bat and #create-android-project.sh then i download these 2 files from the internet and i tried to create project i receive the error. anyone have any idea please kindly help.﻿

.............
Resolved location library project to C:\ADT\cocos2d-x\cocos2dx\platform\android\java
Error: Project folder 'C:\ADT\cocos2d-x\cocos2dx\platform\android\java' is not valid directory
Error: No Android manifest at: C:\ADT\cocos2d-x\cocos2dx\platform\android\java

Error!!!
Don't run in cygwin. You should run corresponding bat.
Press any key to continue.

Comment: if these files did not come with the cocos2d-x archive they probably don't belong to that cocos2d-x version. Consider that the new version is simply installed differently than earlier versions or than described in tutorials. Read the install instructions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by not following the installation instructions (run setup.py).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cocos new ProjName -p com.compnyName.ProjName -l cpp
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [cocos2d-console](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-console) for creating project.

```
$ cocos2d-x-3.1.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin/cocos new -d . -p com.example.testproject -l cpp TestProject
```